# Grails Gorm Query Restriction

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have two domains

```
class ProductQuantity {
    Integer quantity

    static belongsTo = [productSize: ProductSize]
}

class ProductSize {

    String size

    static hasMany = [productQuantities : ProductQuantity]
}
```

I'm trying to build a query where I get all ProductQuantity by the productSize. I have the following query that works.

```
def productSize = ProductSize.findAllById(1);
def productQuantities = ProductQuantity.findAllByProductSize(productSize)
```

I'm looking to get the ProductQuanties in a single query rather than two separate queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ProductQuantity.createCriteria().list {
    eq 'productSize', ProductSize.load(1)
}
```

or

```
ProductQuantity.withCriteria {
    eq 'productSize', ProductSize.load(1)
}
```

or

```
ProductQuantity.where {
    productSize == ProductSize.load(1)
}.list()
```

or

```
ProductQuantity.findAll("from ProductQuantity where productSize = ?", [ProductSize.load(1)])
```

Comment: any particular reason your using load?

Comment: `load` makes way more sense than `get` here. `get` forces a database query, possibly including many columns, large strings, etc. All the `ProductSize` instance is used for is to get its `id` for use as the foreign key in the final SQL. `get` is inefficient since you throw away all the data retrieved from the database and only use the one value you already knew - the `id`. With `load()` you get a Hibernate proxy instead. It has the `id` value and will use it to retrieve the full instance if you access any other property. But since you won't be, there's no unnecessary database access.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get this by [createCriteria](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html), like --

```
def productQuantities = ProductQuantity.createCriteria().list() {
    productSize {
        eq('id', 1)
    }
}
```